# Add "PM Canvas" tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

The Project Model Canvas is a methodology similar to Business Model Canvas to manage projects. The official site is [www.pmcanvas.com.br](http://www.pmcanvas.com.br) (in brazilian portuguese). This technique consists of using canvas to define:

- Justification
- Objectives
- Benefits
- Product
- Requirements
- Stakeholders
- Project team
- Assumptions
- Constraints
- Deliverables
- Risks
- Schedule
- Costs

#### Some Reference

- http://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/changepoint-takes-lead-sponsorship-role-at-project-management-institutes-brazilian-national-congress-283673951.html

Comment: Generally, Stack Exchange is an English-language site. The link you provided isn't in English. Is there a more reputable English description than PR Newswire?

Comment: @CodeGnome I found a link, but does not seems that this methodology is already known outside Brazil or maybe South America. The link is http://blog.myscrumhalf.com/2013/05/project-model-canvas/?lang=en. Is there any restriction in this case to a subject be worthy for a tag?

Comment: The only restriction is that it has to be relevant to questions on PMSE not otherwise served by existing tags. So, if you have a PM Canvas question, or see one here that is using a less optimal tag, the tag can be created at need. However, we generally don't create tags speculatively; tags are created on the fly as a way to normalize and categorize topics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Auto-Vivification of Tags

Generally tags are auto-vivified as needed when used to tag a question. Feel to tag relevant questions, or to create questions under this new tag. If you need help creating a new tag due to insufficient permissions until you gain enough reputation to create new tags:

1. tag the question as best you can from the available pool,
2. comment on the question to suggest a new tag, and then
3. flag the question for moderator/community intervention afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Tags are mainly used to 1) easily identify or find questions and answers on a common topic or 2) monitor specific subjects. In both cases, tags are naturally created once there's enough material to be tagged with (+1 for CG answer!).

Having that said, *if we're not sure whether this tag should be created or not*, it's probably because there isn't enough content @ PMSE over this specific topic or else the *community itself* would have already created it.

The only scenario where the above wouldn't apply that I could think of is when there are several questions with a common 'matter' that could become a tag but no one had noticed it before. For instance, assume we already have several questions that could be tagged as 'canvas' but no one ever mentioned that this was an actual technique. But I don't believe that's the case at the moment.